# RuntimeError: Can not init Myriad device: NC_ERROR on RaspberryPi 3 with NCS Ver. 1

Tags: openvino

I am trying to install OpenVINO on RaspberryPi 3 with NCS. Unfortunately, after several attempts, the procedure which I followed step-by-step was unsuccessful. The procedure itself ran smoothly, without any errors, but I haven't successfully executed any model, neither from examples nor my own. For example, when I try to execute

```
object_detection_sample_ssd -m face-detection-adas-0001.xml -d MYRIAD -i ~/test1.jpg
```

or the python version of the same example, I get:

```
    API version ............ 2.1
        Build .................. 2021.2.0-1877-176bdf51370-releases/2021/2
        Description ....... API
Parsing input parameters
[ INFO ] Files were added: 1
[ INFO ]     /home/pi/test1.jpg
[ INFO ] Loading Inference Engine
[ INFO ] Device info: 
        MYRIAD
        myriadPlugin version ......... 2.1
        Build ........... 2021.2.0-1877-176bdf51370-releases/2021/2
[ INFO ] Loading network files:
        face-detection-adas-0001.xml
[ INFO ] Preparing input blobs
[ INFO ] Batch size is 1
[ INFO ] Preparing output blobs
[ INFO ] Loading model to the device
[ ERROR ] Can not init Myriad device: NC_ERROR
```

The same error appears in my own code, when executing:

```
load_network(network=net, device_name='MYRIAD')
```

The NCS is recognized, and dmesg and lsusb print:

```
[  988.691888] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[  988.822626] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=03e7, idProduct=2150, bcdDevice= 0.01
[  988.822646] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  988.822660] usb 1-1.4: Product: Movidius MA2X5X
[  988.822674] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Movidius Ltd.
[  988.822687] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 03e72150

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03e7:2150 Intel Myriad VPU [Movidius Neural Compute Stick]
```

udev rules are updated with:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2150", ATTRS{idVendor}=="03e7", GROUP="users", MODE="0660", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2485", ATTRS{idVendor}=="03e7", GROUP="users", MODE="0660", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="f63b", ATTRS{idVendor}=="03e7", GROUP="users", MODE="0660", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
```

User pi belongs to users group, and the same error appears also when executing everything as root.

Hardware is Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2, and OS is Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). The PSU is more than powerful enough, with 4.5A.

I know there are a lot of similar posts, I read many, but none of them has helped me to resolve the problem. So, I would appreciate any help or hint how to proceed.

Comment: Just in case that someone else has the same problem, NCS Ver. 1 is not supported by versions of OpenVINO after 2020.3 (including 2020.3.1).

Comment: I had the same Error with an Intel NCS 2, when it was hooked to the Raspberry Pi using a 20cm USB extension cable. After removing it the error disappeared and inference did run without errors.